# Get the value of a Text field in Drupal custom module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am developing a custom module that allows me to create a custom text field where I need to insert a URL for a HTTP Request.

The only thing I would like to do right now is to get the value from the text field and show somewhere in the node.

Here is the .install code :

```
function graph_field_enable() {
  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'graph_field',
    'type' => 'text',
  );
  field_create_field($field);


/**
   * Bind field to a entity bundle.
   */
  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => $field['field_name'],
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'station',
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
}
/**
 * Implements hook_disable().
 *
 * Remove field from node bundle (content type) and then delete the field.
 */

function graph_field_disable() {
  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'graph_field',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'station',
  );
  field_delete_instance($instance);
  field_delete_field($instance['field_name']);
  print 'Removed ' . $instance['field_name'] . "\n";
}
```

The .module file only contains :

```
<?php
```

I'm very new to Drupal and i think i hate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, I want to help flesh out [Neha Singhania](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) answer, but don't have enough rep yet to comment on it.)

If you don't already have the associative array that represents the node, load it using the node id with:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

Once you've got that, you can access any textfield value using either of these, I believe:

```
$node->field_textfieldname['und'][0]['value'];
$node->field_textfieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

The first key in the array specifies what language (undefined/none in those cases), the second key/index says which value of the field (in case you have a multiple value field), and the 3rd is the actual meat and potatoes. For text field, you'll also see:

```
$node->field_textfieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value'];
```

This is, I believe, created/updated on node_save($nid), and it scrubs the value for any illegal/unsafe values.

It's the same for many field types, but not all. But the method's the same. For instance, if you wanted the value for a field type of entity_reference, it'd look something like this.

```
$node->field_entityrferencefieldname['und'][0]['target_id'];
```

Where target_id is an integer/id number of whatever internal entity (node id, user id, etc.) it's referencing. I'd HIGHLY recommend installing the devel module, which gives you the dpm() function; basically, it's a pretty version of print_r, and will display as as Drupal message.

If you stick with Drupal, you're gonna think you hate it at times. A lot. I know. But it's still pretty worth it. (And, from my own experience, seems to make it REALLY easy to find a job...)

Also, this is a question that should probably go on [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
$node = node_load( $nid );
print_r( $node->graph_field );
```

Or you can print the entire node:

```
print_r( $node );
```

Comment: Where do i have to put this code? And what is the $nid variable?

Comment: `$nid` is Node ID. Put it where You want to display the content of `graph_field`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information of any node programmatically, load the node with its node id.
$nid = '1';//This is the first node of your site
$node_info = node_load($nid);
print_r($node_info->field_custom_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);//This will print the value of field_custom_field. You can use any field name here.
And to check this information directly put code in hook_init function for testing, later on you can use where you want.